# A single global variable that is always a random number each time it's referenced

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, global-variables

I'd like to use one global variable that is random every time it's used. My current method creates a random number once and that number stays the same. I don't need the number to be unique, just always random.

```
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
$('something').css('width', randomNumber)
$('something-else').css('width', randomNumber) // want a different random number
$('a-totally-different-thing').css('width', randomNumber) // want another different random number
```

Is there a way to do this, or do I have to use a different var each time? My main reason for wanting this is to keep the code clean and readable and not have to put Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) in over and over again everywhere. I'm experimenting with generative art so it's going to be used a LOT. I'd like it to be global so I can reference it from anywhere.

**Answer: Use a function instead of a variable. Much Thanks to VLAZ and CherryDT**

Comment: Why not create a function that gives you a random number?

Comment: Would the function be inside a global variable so that it runs whenever/wherever the variable is used?

Comment: You would just have a function that you call `getRandomNumber()` and that's it.

Comment: Mind giving me a code example? I'm kind of dumb :)

Comment: `function getRandomNumber() { return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100); }` and then for example you use `$('something').css('width', getRandomNumber())`

Comment: That's it! Thank you, I didn't even know I could call a function like that. I'm very noob.

Comment: That's what you do with `Math.random()` in `Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)` - same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a getter on the global object:

```js
Object.defineProperty(globalThis, 'randomNumber', {
  get: () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
})

console.log(randomNumber)
console.log(randomNumber)
console.log(randomNumber)
```

...but I find this odd and would actually see this as unexpected, confusing behavior if I'd encounter it in code. Why not using a function instead?

```js
function getRandomNumber () {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
}

console.log(getRandomNumber())
console.log(getRandomNumber())
console.log(getRandomNumber())
```